# Como eliminar espaços em branco em volta de determinado caractere?

Tags: php

Como eu posso via preg_replace eliminar espaços entre `/`

Por exemplo:

`Comercial / Vendedor` para `Comercial/Vendedor`

`Compras / Vendas` para `Compras/Vendas`

Desejo isso porque os usuários sempre digitam errado.

Aqui esta o modelo que uso para eliminar linhas por e-mail. Qual seria a expressão para fazer o que desejo acima?

```
function filterEmail($text) {
    return preg_replace('/(.*)[a-z0-9\.\_\-]+@[a-z0-9\.\_\-]+\.[a-z]+(.*)/i','', $text);
}
```

Comment: não estou entendendo porque o pessoal está negativando esta pergunta. Parece ser uma pergunta válida como qualquer outra no site.

Comment: Usar regex pra isso é um exagero, mas isto quem tem que explicar são as respostas e/ou comentários. Não acho que seja caso para negativação (e nem de positivar se for "só pra compensar", pois aí é um erro em cima de outro).

Answer (score 3):

Se for somente para eliminar o espaço entre as barras, utilize o [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php).

```
$str = "Comercial / Vendedor";
echo str_replace(" / ", "/", $str);
```

Saída:

> Comercial/Vendedor

Veja no [ideone](http://ideone.com/80zoQs).

Answer (score 3):

Recomendo usar `str_replace` por causa do desempenho. Apenas a título de curiosidade, é assim que você faria se fosse usar `preg_replace`:

```
$txt = "Compras / Vendas";
echo preg_replace("# / #g", "", $txt);
```

Repare que eu usei `#` como delimitador da regex, ao invés do `/` que é mais usual. Isso porque `/` conflitaria com o nosso regex, que também busca uma barra no texto. Ainda assim, se você quisesse usar `/` como delimitador, seria possível escapar o pattern usando a barra invertida:

```
echo preg_replace("/ \/ /g", "", $txt);
```

Podemos usar [vários símbolos como delimitadores](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) (e.g. `@`, `+`, `%`). É possível também usar pares de abertura e fechamento, como `()`, `{}`, `[]`, `<>`.

Answer (score 3):

A resposta do @MarceloDeAndrade é o caminho mais adequado para o caso exato do problema (e já recebeu meu +1), mas só pra complementar, segue uma versão com *RegEx* aproveitando seu potencial:

```
$str = 'Comercial /Vendedor - Compras/ Vendas - Um     /   Dois';
$str = preg_replace('(\s*/\s*)','/', $str);
echo $str;
```

Neste caso, estamos capturando situações em que o espaço pode variar em quantidade, ou simplesmente não existir.

- Funciona se tiver mais de um espaço ( `a    /         b` );
- funciona se não tiver espaço de algum lado ( `a /b` ou `a/ b` );
- captura outros tipos de espaço em branco (tabulação etc).

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/yUQtb7)**.

Mas como diz [o próprio manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php) sobre `str_replace`, é sempre bom lembrar que:

> Se você não precisa de regras de substituição especiais (como expressões regulares), você sempre poderia usar esta função ao invés de ereg_replace() ou preg_replace().

Comment: +1 Por abranger outras possibilidades.